# How do I grab the console output (and only output) of an other program's application?

Tags: python, bash, console, output

I am writing a python code that will work as a dameon in a Raspberry pi. However, the person I am writing this for want to see the raw output it gets while it is running, not just my log files.

My first idea to do this was to use a bash script using the Screen program, but that has some features in it that I CANNOT have. Mainly the ability to kill the program through the Screen program.

Is there a way I can write a program (preferably python) or bash script, that is able to read the output of another program running, but doesn't send anything to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest is just the bash command

```
tail -f my_logfile.txt
```

this assumes you are already logging to a file ...

if you wish to snoop on another process' stdout stream you can use strace (also bash)

```
export PID=$(pgrep my_program)
strace -p$PID -s9999 -e write
```

Comment: Unless python's print command doesn't go to stdout, I am getting saying it attached to my process but nothing is being shown after it said that process is attached.

Comment: are you running in the same terminal? you may also want to check /var/log/syslog for the output as it might be getting redirected there

Comment: how are you starting the daemon?

Comment: Its a python progarm I wrote, and it doesn't write to the /var/log/syslog/

Its not completely working as a daemon, yet. For now the program is called when running the command "python filename.py [arguments]"

Comment: instead launch it as `python filename.py > /var/log/prog_output.txt 2>&1` then just use `tail -f /var/log/prog_output.txt`

Comment: (hmm actually it seems like that buffer doesnt flush very often ... ) although I just tested strace and it worked fine ... are you sure your program is actually running and outputting data to stdout?

Comment: The redirect method doesn't seem to work, the file is created but nothing is outputted on it.

Comment: it gets written to the file but it does not flush the file often enough to be considered streaming .... again, the strace method works fine however ... alternatively write to a log file inside your program and flush the fille buffer frequently so a `tail -f /var/log/my_log.txt` will show updated data more frequently

Comment: ok I see it now, turns out I was looking at the wrong PID as the PID I was getting was the bash file it launched from.

Anyway is there a way to filter it to only get what is being sent to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

You may get the stdout stream by calling

```
cat /proc/<pid>/fd/1
```